# how can see how many vtable and vpointer created for my program in program level

Tags: c++, unix, vtable

here is my program , I am little confuse about how many `vtable` and `virtualpointe`r will be created for the program. and if we don't create a virtual function in derive class will `vpinter` will create for that.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class abc
{
    virtual void  aaa();
};
void abc::aaa()
{
}
class ddd:public abc
{
    void ddda();
    virtual void sddd();
};
void ddd::ddda()
{
}
void ddd::sddd()
{
}
int main()
{
    abc d;
    ddd *y;
    abc *ab;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what actual problem are you trying to solve? Although I'm generally aware of the basic principals of typical virtual inheritance implementations, I can't say that in the 25 years of hacking C++ I really cared about vtable implementation particulars, nor how many different actual vtables or virtual pointers my program creates. That's my C++ compiler's job, to figure it out; and I'm happy to let my compiler do its job. Unless, of course, my job is to write a C++. But it's not. So, unless you're writing your own C++ compiler, I don't see why you would care, about something like this.

Comment: baesd on the creation of the vpointer i will have the clear idea on how at run time virtual function is invoked

Comment: A vtable is an implementation detail.   Although it is a common implementation approach, it is not a required approach.    In any event, unless you are debugging a C++ compiler, you would not need visibility of the creation of vtables.   And, if you are debugging a C++ compiler, you would know how to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had read some information from "Effective C++","every class has a virtual table if it has virtual function,the virtual table will include the virtual pointer of virtual function".I think it will help you.